# Plan for hot replacing damaged RAID-1 drive in freebsd 9.0

Tags: raid, freebsd

**i have System FreeBSD 9.0 with RAID configuration**

```
# mfiutil show config
mfi0 Configuration: 2 arrays, 2 volumes, 0 spares
    array 0 of 2 drives:
        drive  4 (  558G) ONLINE <SEAGATE ST3600057SS 0008 serial=6SL3ZTFP> SAS
        drive  5 (  558G) ONLINE <SEAGATE ST3600057SS 0008 serial=6SL3YNB7> SAS
    array 1 of 2 drives:
        drive  6 (  558G) ONLINE <SEAGATE ST3600057SS 0008 serial=6SL3YNK3> SAS
        drive  7 (  558G) ONLINE <SEAGATE ST3600057SS 0008 serial=6SL3YQNJ> SAS
    volume mfid0 (557G) RAID-1 64k OPTIMAL spans:
            array 0
    volume mfid1 (1115G) RAID-0 64k OPTIMAL spans:
            array 1
```

**At last time i see many warn records for drive PD 05 (part of raid-1)**

```
89584 (Fri Apr 27 20:33:16 ALMT 2018/DRIVE/WARN) - Predictive failure: PD 05(e0xfc/s1)
89906 (Sat Apr 28 20:33:16 ALMT 2018/DRIVE/WARN) - Predictive failure: PD 05(e0xfc/s1)
89907 (Sun Apr 29 20:33:16 ALMT 2018/DRIVE/WARN) - Predictive failure: PD 05(e0xfc/s1)
89908 (Mon Apr 30 20:33:16 ALMT 2018/DRIVE/WARN) - Predictive failure: PD 05(e0xfc/s1)
89909 (Tue May  1 20:33:16 ALMT 2018/DRIVE/WARN) - Predictive failure: PD 05(e0xfc/s1)
```

**The system installed on raid-1**

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/mfid0p2    544G    381G    119G    76%    /
devfs           1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /dev
/dev/mfid1s2    972G    408G    486G    46%    /home2
/dev/md2         31M     56k     28M     0%    /tmp/mem
```

Now i buy new drive ST3600057SS and have have plan to hot replace drive

```
1) mfiutil fail 5
2) mfiutil locate 5 on
3) replace drive
4) mfiutil rebuild 5
5) mfiutil start rebuild 5
```

i’m not really sure, can someone tell me, all steps in my plan is right?

Thank you for attention!

Answer (score 1):

Operation for replace drive complected without problems!
after replace drive raid-1 going to rebuild and was done ~ 1 hour

```
mfi0: 90563 (579439206s/0x0002/info) - State change on PD 05(e0xfc/s1) from ONLINE(18) to FAILED(11)
mfi0: 90564 (579439206s/0x0001/info) - State change on VD 00/0 from OPTIMAL(3) to DEGRADED(2)
mfi0: 90565 (579439206s/0x0001/CRIT) - VD 00/0 is now DEGRADED
mfi0: 90566 (579439279s/0x0002/WARN) - Removed: PD 05(e0xfc/s1)
mfi0: 90567 (579439279s/0x0002/info) - Removed: PD 05(e0xfc/s1) Info: enclPd=fc, scsiType=0, portMap=01, sasAddr=5000c5004cd40ca5,0000000000000000
mfi0: 90568 (579439279s/0x0002/info) - State change on PD 05(e0xfc/s1) from FAILED(11) to UNCONFIGURED_BAD(1)
mfi0: 90569 (579439450s/0x0002/info) - Inserted: PD 08(e0xfc/s1)
mfi0: 90570 (579439450s/0x0002/info) - Inserted: PD 08(e0xfc/s1) Info: enclPd=fc, scsiType=0, portMap=01, sasAddr=5000c50088a32c3d,0000000000000000
mfi0: 90571 (579439450s/0x0002/info) - State change on PD 08(e0xfc/s1) from UNCONFIGURED_GOOD(0) to OFFLINE(10)
mfi0: 90572 (579439450s/0x0002/info) - Rebuild automatically started on PD 08(e0xfc/s1)
mfi0: 90573 (579439450s/0x0002/info) - State change on PD 08(e0xfc/s1) from OFFLINE(10) to REBUILD(14)


mfi0 Configuration: 2 arrays, 2 volumes, 0 spares
    array 0 of 2 drives:
        drive  4 (  559G) ONLINE <SEAGATE ST3600057SS 0008 serial=6SL3ZTFP> SAS
        drive  8 (  559G) REBUILD <SEAGATE ST3600057SS 000B serial=6SLA5GTM> SAS
    array 1 of 2 drives:
        drive  6 (  559G) ONLINE <SEAGATE ST3600057SS 0008 serial=6SL3YNK3> SAS
        drive  7 (  559G) ONLINE <SEAGATE ST3600057SS 0008 serial=6SL3YQNJ> SAS
    volume mfid0 (558G) RAID-1 64K DEGRADED spans:
        array 0
    volume mfid1 (1116G) RAID-0 64K OPTIMAL spans:
        array 1
```

Thank you!